# How to optimize select_related with limit/offset selection?

Tags: mysql, django

Example:

```
# consider the following query run in a loop
q = Users.objects.all().select_related('profile', 'address')[start:start+batchsize]

# assume start == 1,000,000 and batchsize == 1000
print q.query

SELECT ... LEFT OUTER JOIN profile ... LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000000;
```

Problem:

Using select_related here speeds up my query because otherwise, django will make extra DB calls to get profile/address (and many other tables) when I access them later in a loop. However, while this speeds up the beginning of the iterations, when OFFSET is large, it actually slows down.

1) Has anyone else experienced this issue?
2) Is there any workaround in django to solve this problem?

I kind of suspect this is a problem with MySQL query engine, but just want to know if I can structure my django code to maybe help out the query optimizer in MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to hydrate objects into "q"? Or do you really just need certain values? like those that would be returned by returning a values_list instead of objects.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing really to "workaround" here. This is expected behavior. `select_related` does a SQL JOIN for each foreign key you feed it. This is an inherently more complex query for the database to process. The more rows in your tables the longer it will take.

Really, all you can do in this scenario is apply as much optimization to your table as possible. If the `profile_id` and `address_id` columns are not already indexed, you should add indexes for them (but I have a suspicion Django has already done that for you.

If you don't need all the fields, you can try sending a more limited query (requiring less net work to process) using `.values()` or `.values_list()`. You can even specify fields on `profile` and `address` in there.

However, if those fields are indexed already, and you need all the data, you either have to just deal with the slowness or take some more drastic measures with your database. You can seclude it to its own server if it's not already, give the server more resources (RAM, cores, etc.) if it's underpowered, create a cluster to divvy out the load, etc.